# Jmeter is skipping the HTTP request when running no error in logs

Tags: jmeter, soapui

jmeter while running is not sending HTTP request only i see one request in the result tree
[image]

Comment: perhaps review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

In case if anything goes wrong or JMeter doesn't do what it is supposed to be doing first thing to check is [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Most probably something is wrong with your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration.

If jmeter.log doesn't contain suspicious entries you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to DEBUG level.

Comment: I Have enabled the debug for the run but didnt get any useful information. i see that the second request is being formed but not executed log file : https://pastebin.mozilla.org/83A54zuc